# Standby mode current consumption is not reduced to expected value

Tags: stm32

I am trying to measure the current consumption in STM32L011F4 microcontroller. I tried the STANDBY mode sample code provide by STM in 'stm32cubel0'. Standby mode current consumption is about 320µA when I measured it using a multimeter. The datasheet says that the maximum current consumption is 0.6µA for temperature between -40°C to 25°C with Independent watchdog and LSI OFF. The code is shown below. Does anyone have an idea why the current consumption is more that expected?

```c
int main(void)
{
  /* STM32L0xx HAL library initialization */
  HAL_Init();



  /* Configure the system clock to 2 MHz */
  SystemClock_Config();



  /* System Power Configuration */
  SystemPower_Config()  ;

  /* Check if the system was resumed from Standby mode */
  if (__HAL_PWR_GET_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_SB) != RESET)
  {
    /* Clear Standby flag */
    __HAL_PWR_CLEAR_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_SB);
  }



  /* Insert 5 seconds delay */
  HAL_Delay(5000);



 /* The Following Wakeup sequence is highly recommended prior to each Standby mode entry
    mainly when using more than one wakeup source this is to not miss any wakeup event.
     - Disable all used wakeup sources,
     - Clear all related wakeup flags,
     - Re-enable all used wakeup sources,
     - Enter the Standby mode.
  */



  /* Disable all used wakeup sources: PWR_WAKEUP_PIN3 */
  HAL_PWR_DisableWakeUpPin(PWR_WAKEUP_PIN3);



  /* Clear all related wakeup flags*/
  __HAL_PWR_CLEAR_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_WU);

  /* Enable WakeUp Pin PWR_WAKEUP_PIN3 connected to PA.02 (Arduino A7) */
  HAL_PWR_EnableWakeUpPin(PWR_WAKEUP_PIN3);



  /* Enter the Standby mode */
  HAL_PWR_EnterSTANDBYMode();



  /* This code will never be reached! */
  while (1)
  {
  }
}



/**
  * @brief  System Clock Configuration
  *         The system Clock is configured as follow :
  *            System Clock source            = MSI
  *            SYSCLK(Hz)                     = 2000000
  *            HCLK(Hz)                       = 2000000
  *            AHB Prescaler                  = 1
  *            APB1 Prescaler                 = 1
  *            APB2 Prescaler                 = 1
  *            Flash Latency(WS)              = 0
  *            Main regulator output voltage  = Scale3 mode
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};

  /* Enable MSI Oscillator */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_MSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIState = RCC_MSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIClockRange = RCC_MSIRANGE_5;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSICalibrationValue=0x00;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct)!= HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Initialization Error */
    while(1);
  }

  /* Select MSI as system clock source and configure the HCLK, PCLK1 and PCLK2
     clocks dividers */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = (RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK |  RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1 | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2);
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_MSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;  
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;  
  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0)!= HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Initialization Error */
    while(1);
  }
  /* Enable Power Control clock */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* The voltage scaling allows optimizing the power consumption when the device is
     clocked below the maximum system frequency, to update the voltage scaling value
     regarding system frequency refer to product datasheet.  */
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE3);

  /* Disable Power Control clock */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_DISABLE();

}



/**
  * @brief  System Power Configuration
  *         The system Power is configured as follow :
  *            + VREFINT OFF, with fast wakeup enabled
  *            + No IWDG
  *            + Wakeup using PWR_WAKEUP_PIN3
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void SystemPower_Config(void)
{
  /* Enable Power Control clock */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();



  /* Enable Ultra low power mode */
  HAL_PWREx_EnableUltraLowPower();

  /* Enable the fast wake up from Ultra low power mode */
  HAL_PWREx_EnableFastWakeUp();
}

/**
  * @brief Enters Standby mode.
  * @note In Standby mode, all I/O pins are high impedance except for:
  *          - Reset pad (still available) 
  *          - RTC_AF1 pin (PC13) if configured for tamper, time-stamp, RTC
  *            Alarm out, or RTC clock calibration out.
  *          - RTC_AF2 pin (PC13) if configured for tamper.
  *          - WKUP pin 1 (PA00) if enabled.
  *          - WKUP pin 2 (PC13) if enabled.
  *          - WKUP pin 3 (PE06) if enabled, for stm32l07xxx and stm32l08xxx devices only.
  *          - WKUP pin 3 (PA02) if enabled, for stm32l031xx devices only.
  * @retval None
  */
void HAL_PWR_EnterSTANDBYMode(void)
{
  /* Select Standby mode */
  SET_BIT(PWR->CR, PWR_CR_PDDS);

  /* Set SLEEPDEEP bit of Cortex System Control Register */
  SET_BIT(SCB->SCR, SCB_SCR_SLEEPDEEP_Msk);

  /* This option is used to ensure that store operations are completed */
#if defined ( __CC_ARM)
  __force_stores();
#endif
  /* Request Wait For Interrupt */
  __WFI();
}
```

Comment: I would suspect a couple of things: 1) Your multimeter is not accurate at low-current readings and 2) your board has other components that are still consuming power, and are not isolated from your measurement. What board and meter are you using, and how are you accomplishing the measurement?

Comment: I am using Voltcraft VC280 multimeter in combination with µcurrent GOLD for higher accuracy and to reduce burden voltage. I was also using ST-LINK/V2 (an in-circuit debugger and programmer) for debugging and loading the program. I removed the wires connecting to ST-LINK/V2 and the current consumption reduced to 2.8µA which is great! I have an accelerometer and RFID IC on the PCB and measurements are done without isolating the microcontroller. Turning on of the RFID is controlled by the microcontroller. So it has no effect on current consumption.

Comment: The total supply current for the accelerometer is 13µA in low power mode (according to the datasheet).

Answer (score 1):

You'll find these 'ultra-low-power' claims a bit of bait-n-switch :-)

I've been working with STML152x and STML071x. *>MY<* experience is that you need to DISABLE (aka: DeInit) any pins with pull-up/pull-down to get the very low current. For example, with an L073RZT6 I can get it down to about 4uA in STOP+RTC mode with ext LSE of 32K, but only by killing all the perf's, which I then must again Init() on wake-up. I am GUESSING that pull-up/pull-down somehow prevents the internal Pwr Reg from truly shutting down to lowest power - as I said, that's a guess.

I also gave up on the use of any "PWR_WAKEUP_PINx", as those seem to add about 35uA of sleep current (per Spec they have internal pull-down). Instead I define that pin as GPIO_Input (with external 100K pullup) and enable IRQ support. It wakes up from STOP just fine. In my products, I have a mag reed switch, so users 'swipe' outside the case, and magnet wakes the device. This GPIO is the ONLY GPIO I leave not set to GPIO_Analog when I sleep (and accomplish my 4uA). Fortunately, our products tend to wake up once per 5, 15, or even 60 MINUTES. So the CPU cost to wake/sleep isn't as critical as the 99.999% of time it finds itself in DeepSleep.

With the L152x (Cortex M3), I was able to CHEAT and 'cache' the ->MODER and ->PUPDN values in SRAM, then clear before sleep. Then after waking, restore these and life is good. I've NOT found that working on the L07x (CM0 only), so have to do more work. I know this sounds counter-intuitive, that these chips are DESIGNED to deep-sleep, but it took me weeks of trial-n-error get get the ultra-low sleep current!

One other warning, STM32 CubeMX doesn't properly handle wakeup with HSI-only running. Chip wakes up assuming can switch to MSI, so either enable MSI, or read your docs about how to enable wake-up-to-use-HSI clock (is a bit in RCC->CFGR)

Comment: Oh, you also need to DISABLE all the port clocks, which you re-enable after waking. So with: __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_DISABLE(); etc. The online 'sample programs' tend to be too simplistic and skip such details.